# Is there any way to return the authentication mobile number of a user given their Object ID in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a tenant in Azure B2C that uses a phone number to sign up users in my active directory. When I use the Microsoft Graph API to get the list of users, it does not return the  correct userPrincipalName (it is supposed to be the phone number (appears correctly in the dashboard) but instead the API returns this field value as the Object ID). Is there any way to extract this? I want to be able to fetch a user's mobile number using the Object ID.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can try this api(  h t tp s:/ /graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}  ) to check if it can return mobile phone number in response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this endpoint

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/authentication/phoneMethods/{ObjectId}
```

The response will contan a phone number.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Authentication numbers are not currently supported in /v1.0, but can be found in /beta.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{id | userPrincipalName}/authentication/phoneMethods/{id}
```

refer to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)